# NextJS per page layout not working with typescript

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am developing new application in NextJS 12 using typescript. I have defined two pages register and home page and i want to apply different layout to this pages, i have followed official next js documentation for this, i can see the "Registration Page" text in browser but layout not applying on page output, am i missing something in code? below is my code.

**register.tsx**

```
const UserRegistration: NextPageWithLayout = () => {
    return <h1>Registration Page</h1>
}

UserRegistration.getLayout = (page: ReactElement) => {
    return (
        <DefaultLayout>{page}</DefaultLayout>
    )
}

export default UserRegistration;
```

**_app.tsx**

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppPropsWithLayout) {
  const getLayout = Component.getLayout || ((page) => page)
  return getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />)
}

export default MyApp
```

**type.ts**

```
export type NextPageWithLayout = NextPage & { getLayout: (page: ReactElement) => ReactNode };

export type AppPropsWithLayout = AppProps & { Component: NextPageWithLayout }

export type DefaultLayoutType = { children: ReactNode }
```

**layout.tsx**

```
const DefaultLayout = ({ children }: DefaultLayoutType) => {
    return(
        <div id="main">
            <nav>
                <li>
                    Home
                </li>
            </nav>
            {children}
        </div>
    )
}

export default DefaultLayout;
```

Comment: That code works for me, see https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-brook-93hbh9 and go to `/register`. What's your `pages` folder structure like?

Comment: Hi @juliomalves. Thanks for your reply, code you shared use javascript and my code in typescript. can you try the same code with typescript and share with me?

Comment: Are you getting any TypeScript error? I don't think TypeScript is relevant if you're not seeing a TypeScript-related error.

Comment: @juliomalves I am not seeing any typescript error, but the layout functionality also not working i don't know why.